# Detecting Facebook Login Swift iOS

Tags: facebook, swift, session

I cannot detect whether a user has an open Facebook session in Swift.  I have used the UIView and turned it into a FBLoginView for the user to sign in and out of Facebook.  However, once the user is signed in (or not signed in), I cannot detect each case.  Could someone inform me why this code does not work?

```
    if FBSession.activeSession().state == FBSessionState.CreatedTokenLoaded 
    {
        //something
    }
    else
    {
       //something else
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works when I turn it into a FBLoginViewDelegate rather than FBLoginView